# Lasso. How to use it to predict?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

could you please help with the following question:

I have built the following model using Lasso:

Already looked into documentation
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-lasso-coordinate-descent-path-py

```
lassomodel = PolynomialLasso(4)

x=dfs[['WSales']]

y=dfs[['DSales']]

lassomodel.fit(x, y)

X_lasso=np.linspace(0,4000000,100)[:, None]

y_lasso = lassomodel.predict(X_lasso)

mse=mean_squared_error(lassomodel.predict(x), y)

r2=r2_score(lassomodel.predict(x),y)

print ("Ridge Mean Square Error: ",mse)
print ("Ridge R2-score: ",r2 )
print('Mean absolute error: %.2f' % mean_absolute_error(lassomodel.predict(x), y))


print ("------------------------------------")
plt.plot(X_lasso.ravel(), y_lasso, color='C3',label='y_lasso')
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro', label='y', color='C1')

plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$') 
plt.title(r'Linear Regression - 4.order polynomial') 
plt.legend()
plt.show()
Ridge Mean Square Error:  48063700655.292915
Ridge R2-score:  0.726828587296103
Mean absolute error: 165786.75
```

My question is - if I want to predict y using x value 3 000 000 (for e.g.) with the model that was built, how do I do that (what code should I run)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You're already doing prediction with your model: `lassomodel.predict(x)`. You just sup in the new data for the `x` here to predict.

Comment: If I try lassomodel.predict(x) and use x = 3500000 I get the following error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=3500000.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: My question is how to get a single y value if I set a single x value? For e.g. if I use SLR, I can do this: Sales_prediction = 500000
NVL_pred = regr.coef_*Sales_prediction + regr.intercept_
In order to predict NVL_pred based on Sales_prediction. And I don't understand how to do similar thing here.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for clarifying. The model expects an array of values, not a single value, but you can trick it by passing it as an array of a single value. How about `np.array(3500000.0).reshape(-1, 1)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help, added my last comment as an answer so you could accept it if you like

Answer (score 0):

The model expects an array of values, not a single value, but you can trick it by passing it as an array of a single value. As an example, for the single value `3500000.0`

`lassomodel.predict(np.array(3500000.0).reshape(-1, 1))`